# C# WPF pausing an animated window with storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, storyboard

I am making a C# wpf application with Visual Studio 2012. Here is the toast like notification. It is animated to go off by 4 seconds. It I get the mouse over this I want to pause the animation.

How can I achieve that ?

```
<Window x:Class="Exmaple.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
Title="Notification Popup" Width="300" SizeToContent="Height"
WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Height="Auto"    Background="Transparent">

<Grid x:Name="abc" RenderTransformOrigin="0,1" Height="Auto" Width="300"  Margin="0,0,0,0" MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter_1" >

    <!-- Notification area -->
    <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF2D2D30" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <!--StackPanel Margin="20"-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="textblocknotify" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto"   Margin="5" Foreground="White">

            </TextBlock>
            <!--CheckBox Content="Checkable" Margin="5 5 0 5" /-->
            <!--Button Content="Clickable" HorizontalAlignment="Center" /-->
        <!--/StackPanel-->
    </Border>
    <!-- Animation -->



    <Grid.Triggers >
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard  Completed="Storyboard_Completed_1">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.5" Value="1"/>
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard  Completed="Storyboard_Completed_1">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.5" Value="1"/>
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>



    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>


</Grid>
```

Code behind this

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1(String s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textblocknotify.Text = s;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() =>
        {

            var workingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
            var transform = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;
            var corner = transform.Transform(new Point(workingArea.Right, workingArea.Bottom));

            this.Left = corner.X - this.ActualWidth - 10;
            this.Top = corner.Y - this.ActualHeight-30;
        }));

        //this.Close();
    }

    private void Storyboard_Completed_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       //don't know what to do   

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`PauseStoryboard` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pausestoryboard(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`UIElement.MouseEnter` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx) to pause a running `Animation`. Equally, if you want the `Animation` to resume when the mouse is no longer over the control, then you can use the [`ResumeStoryboard` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.resumestoryboard(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`UIElement.MouseLeave` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is a simple example to demonstrate:

```
<Button Content="Click Me">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Name="OpacityStoryboard">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                        From="0" To="1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
            <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpacityStoryboard" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
            <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpacityStoryboard" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the well- structured answer. Perfectly working.